# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automated-tests

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-active"}

While writing cssSelector like this .ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-active am getting the above error,My automation browser not selecting the current date,Please help me with this...

I am expecting my automated browsers should select the current date in the calendar

Answer (score 0):

**NoSuchElementException** is one of the most common exceptions in Selenium WebDriver, and it is thrown when an HTML element cannot be found.

This means your selector doesn't match any element from your HTML.

Without seeing the source HTML it's tough to give the exact cause.

But here are a few pieces of advice:

1. Go to your page where you are trying to find an element > Open developer tools (F12 in Chrome) > Navigate to the Elements tab > press Ctrl + F > paste your selector (.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight.ui-state-active). If no elements are found - then your selector is incorrect.
2. You are using *-highlight and *-active classes in you selector. Such classes are usually added by JS when clicking on/hovering the mouse over the element. Try to refresh the page (but don't move the mouse to your target HTML element) and check the classes of the target element again.